# "something" validation failed : array.0: cast to [ObjectId] failed for value | React Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

This is my Model

```
isbn: {type: String, required: true},
titre: {type: String, required: true},
annedition: {type: Number, required: true},
prix: {type: Number, required: true},
qtestock: {type: Number, required: true},
couverture: {type: String, required: true},
specialite: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:Specialite, required: true},
maised: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:editeurs, required: true},
auteurs: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:Auteur, required: true}],
```

the auteurs field is an array of ObjectId.
this is the state i am facing an error with.

```
const [auteurs, setAuteurs] = useState([]);
```

i pushed 2 values in the state auteurs with this method and console logged them it works fine

```
const handleChange = async (event) => {
setAuteurs((state) => [...state, event.target.value]);};
```

but when i send the data to the API the Error 409 Conflict appears.
this what i get in the console
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiE2n.png)

Comment: I did not understand this part: _"I pushed 2 values in the state auteurs with this method and console logged them it works fine"_ Can you expand on or rephrase it?

Comment: ... and the SO community usually asks for Error Messages as  formatted **text** rather than attaching images